# run a subroutine by using argument

Tags: perl

My code:

```
my $aaa = "abc";   
sub myp{
  print "$_";
}
myp($aaa);
```

I hope myp can print the argument it get.
But it said 
Use of uninitialized value $_ in string at ./arg line 17.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The arguments to a subroutine in Perl are passed in the `@_` array. This is not the same as the `$_` variable.

A common idiom is to "unpack" these arguments in the first line of a function, e.g.

```
sub example {
   my ($arg1, $arg2) = @_;
   print "$arg1 and $arg2";
}
```

It's also possible to refer to arguments directly as elements of `@_`, e.g. as `$_[0]`, but this is much harder to read and as such is best avoided.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do something like:

```
my $first_arg = shift @_;
my $second_arg = shift @_;
```

You can also use the method of the other response:

```
my ($first_arg, $second_arg) = @_;
```

But be careful saying:

```
my $first_arg = @_;
```

Since you will get the number of arguments passed to the subroutine.

When you refer to `$_` you are referencing the default string variable, you probably want in this case to refer `@_`, if you want to get a specific argument, you must say `$_[narg]`, be also careful passing arrays to subroutines if you do:

```
some_sub(@myarray);
```

You will pass the entire array as it was the argument list, instead you should say:

```
some_sub(\@myarray);
```